# The multi-touch functionality from my Magic Mouse is frustrating with Google Calendar. Can I disable it?

Tags: multi-touch

...The tiniest swipe left or right changes the month. It makes using my calendar sooooo frustrating. Can I disable it? I would like to disable side-swiping in general. It mostly causes me frustration.

Is there a way?

Comment: just fixed it by installing MagicPrefs ... but still interested in answers. Especially, if it helps somebody else that is searching for the answer.

Comment: 1. Install Magic Prefs 
2. Click link to 'Configure Scrolling' below picture of mouse
3. Un-check 'Horizonal Scrolling' for single swipe

Comment: "Can I disable it?" Yes! You can definitely disable Google Calendar!

Comment: ha @AlanShutko what is your favorite desktop calendar app (needs to sync with google calendar)

Comment: I just don't use google calendar at all.  But I do like Fantastical 2, and it will sync with Google Calendar.